# how to sort date today onwards in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
2021-05-31T22:59:59Z
2022-05-11T22:59:59Z
2022-06-21T22:59:59Z
2022-05-28T22:59:59Z
2022-06-31T22:59:59Z
2022-11-30T23:59:59Z
```

how to sort date based on today date suppose today date is 2021-11-25T21:59:59Z then our date should be sort  like this

```
    2022-05-11T22:59:59Z
    2022-05-28T22:59:59Z
    2022-06-21T22:59:59Z
    2022-06-31T22:59:59Z
    2022-11-30T23:59:59Z
    2021-05-31T22:59:59Z

dates.sortedByDescending {
            (it.toFormattedFullDateFullTime).millis.toInt() >  currentDateTimeUTC.millis.toInt()

}
```

but i am unable to to this please help me how to sort date based on current date .

Comment: I was not able to understand your question clearly. Do you mean to sort from old to new dates? why is 2021-05-31T22:59:59Z at the end in your expected result?

Comment: Sorry i don't want to display that date i just want display date from today date onwards we have to sort in that manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below

```
 val result = dates.sortedByDescending {
        LocalDate.parse(it, ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault()))
    }

    println(result)
```

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-05-31T22:59:59Z' could not be parsed: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 22 i am getting this exception

Comment: @MARSH : I have updated my answer please check it. It's works fine now.